# how to communicate using functions that share similar instance variable?

Tags: java, function

How can I update the raise salary to reflect on annual salary? Assuming I have created an object from class to access them if salary was 10,000, then salary raise of 2% gives me the updated salary as well as updating the annual function?

```
public class Employee {
    private String first_Name;
    private int id;
    private String last_Name;
    private double salary;

    public Employee(String first_Name, String last_Name, int id, double salary) {
        this.first_Name = first_Name;
        this.last_Name = last_Name;
        this.id = id;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    // Getters + setters...

    public double get_Annual_Salary() {
        return salary * 12;
    }

    public double raise_Salary(double p) {
        // raise salary by percentage (e.g 2% etc)
        return salary * p / 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: `salary = salary * (1 + p / 100);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Robby Cornelissen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3558960/robby-cornelissen) points out the formula to calculate the updated salary is `salary = salary * (1 + p / 100);`

Using that you can modify your `raise_salary` method to update the local salary variable.

```
public double raise_Salary(double p) {
        salary = salary * (1 + p / 100);
        return salary;
    }
```

Now when you call the `get_Annual_Salary()` method it will return the annual salary using the employee's updated salary.